# Why AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY is not a half of the day?

Tags: android

Here is how I schedule my alarm:

```
public void scheduleAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AliveService_.class);
        PendingIntent serviceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, serviceIntent);
    }
```

Then, using the `adb shell dumpsys alarm` command I see:

> ELAPSED #4: Alarm{427c2a40 type 3 my.package.name}
>       type=3 **when=+4h35m36s353ms** repeatInterval=43200000 count=0
>       operation=PendingIntent{42a5d0d0: PendingIntentRecord{42bf84a0 my.package.name startService}}

Saying the alarm to be triggered in `4h35m36s353ms` which is not actually a half of the day. Why?

More to say, the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) are saying:

> Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time

Comment: because read the documentation. `the alarm will be phase-aligned with other alarms to reduce the number of wakeups.`

Comment: @njzk2 It is also stated "Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why?

A few reasons.

First, you called `setInexactRepeating()`, which means that Android gets to schedule your event whenever it wants to, no sooner than your initial time, but up to `INTERVAL_HALF_DAY` later.

Second, you passed an initial time of `INTERVAL_HALF_DAY`, with a type of `ELAPSED_REALTIME`. That means you want your first alarm event to occur 12 hours after your phone was last rebooted. That is probably in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Your first alarm is most certainly not going to go off when you expect.

The second argument to [`setInexactRepeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) is:

> long triggerAtMillis: time in milliseconds that the alarm should first
>   go off.

Since you are passing in `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY`, you are sending it a trigger time of 43200000, one half day after the Unix epoch, and around 40 years ago.

**Note:** As per CommonsWare's comment below, this only applies if you change your alarm's type to `RTC` or `RTC_WAKEUP`. If your intent is to deliver an alarm every half day (not a half day since the last reboot), you will encounter this issue.

Comment: That would be true if the alarm type were `RTC`. In this case, it is the number of milliseconds since the last reboot (`ELAPSED_REALTIME`). That being said, this parameter is probably the source of the difficulty.